# Read XML for options in update panel (php jquery)

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I found a neat solution for mouse over update panel, real simple.

What I'd like to do is read the 'options' from xml instead of static string like this example:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
                    var options = {'solutions':"<h1 class='middleh1'>Solving Your Tech Problems.</h1><p>Below are a couple of areas that Felecan specializes in:<ul><li>Web Application Development</li><li>Search Engine Marketing</li><ul>",'passion':"<h1 class='middleh1'>Welcome To Felecan!</h1><p>Felecan believes in helping companies and individuals realize their full potential on the Internet with top of the line tools and support. This means fast response times, and help for your technology problems right away.</p>",'technology':"<h1 class='middleh1'>Technology Done Right.</h1><p>From PHP to Python, the Django framework, and jQuery for JavaScript/Ajax your ideas can become professional products for less than you thought!"}
                    var array = ['solutions','technology','passion'];
                    random =Math.floor(Math.random()*2)
                    $("#doc_box_right").html(options['passion']);
                    $("#solutions").css("cursor","pointer");
                    $("#technology").css("cursor","pointer");
                    $("#passion").css("cursor","pointer");
                    $("#solutions").mouseover(function() {
                        $("#doc_box_right").html(options.solutions);
                    });
                    $("#passion").mouseover(function() {
                        $("#doc_box_right").html(options.passion);
                    });
                    $("#technology").mouseover(function() {
                        $("#doc_box_right").html(options.technology);
                    });
                });

<div id="doc_box_left">
                    <ul style="list-style-image: url(http://www.felecan.com/media/images/arrow.png);">
                        <li id="passion">Passion</li>
                        <li id="solutions">Solutions</li>
                        <li id="technology">Technology</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div id="doc_box_right">
                </div>
```

I need to create the options, cursor pointers, and mouseover effects all from an xml doc I have.  The xml doc has nodes with two attributes:

```
<statements>
<statement title="A Title" statement="The statement"/>
<statement title="Another Title" statement="The statement for this"/>
</statements>
```

the title would be the list items, the statement would be the update in the html 'doc_box_right'

WORKING solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "php/docstatement_genxml.php",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: parseXml
        });
    });
    function parseXml(xml) {
        var items = [];
        $(xml).find("statement").each(function () {
            var title = $(this).attr("title");
            var titleid = (title.substr(0, 8)).replace(" ", "_");
            items.push('<li id="' + titleid + '">' + title + '</li>');
        });
        $('#doclist').append(items.join(''));
        $(xml).find("statement").each(function () {
            var title = $(this).attr("title");
            var titleid = (title.substr(0, 8)).replace(" ", "_");
            var id = '#' + titleid;
            var statement = $(this).attr("text");
            $(id).css("cursor", "pointer");
            $(id).mouseover(function () {
                $("#doc_box_right").html('<h2>' + title + '</h2><p>' + statement + '</p>');
            });
        });

    }
</script>

            <div id="doctrine_box">
                <div id="doc_box_left">
                    <ul id="doclist">
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div id="doc_box_right">
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: there was a problem with threading in the javascript also.  that's why I had to append the list items BEFORE I put the selectors and events on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<statements>
<statement title="A Title" statement="The statement" id="title_a"/>
<statement title="Another Title" statement="The statement for this" id="title_b"/>
</statements>

var xml_id = $(this).attr("id");
$("#" + xml_id).css("cursor", "pointer");
```

`$("#" + title)` is read as `$('#A title')`, this seems to be the problem

Comment: I added a titleid variable that addressed this problem but it doesn't seem to parse.  I added an alert pop up to the parseXML function and it never ran???

Comment: @Chris : `var title = $(this).attr("title");`, discard the `.ValueOf`